# Is there a better way to add/remove 'B's from my string in Perl?

Tags: perl

Have many lines of text

some lines has the following pattern `/^aaa(B+)(.*)/`

- start with "aaa"
- followed by a number of "B" (1 up to 9)
- remainder of the line

need construct a function what get:

- the text in a scalar, and
- the shifting parameter how to shift the number of Bs

for example:

```
change_ab(2,$text)  # and the function will add 2 B
change_ab(-1, $text) #the function will remove one B
```

**EDIT: added some examples - (in the result need to have min 1B or max 9Bs) - in my source code are these conditions, but i forgot write it here (sry))**

```
 shifting   from     result
    2       aaaB     aaaBBB
    3       aaaBB    aaaBBBBB
   -2       aaaBBBB  aaaBB
   -3       aaaBB    aaaB          #min.1
    9       aaaBBBB  aaaBBBBBBBBB  #max.9
```

my solution is splitting the scalar text into lines. Not very elegant. :(

Exists some better/faster solution - like one big regex without the need of splitting?

Here is my code:

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;

my $mytext = "some text
aaaB some another text
text3 here
aaaBB some text4
another textxxx
aaaBBBBXX some text4
another textzzzz
";

say change_ab(-1,$mytext);

sub change_ab {
    my($bshift, $text) = @_;

    my $out = "";
    foreach my $line ( split(/[\r\n]/, $text) ) {
        if( $line =~ /^aaa(B+)(.*)/) {
            my $bcnt = length($1);    
            my $wantedBcnt = $bcnt + $bshift;
            $wantedBcnt = 1 if $wantedBcnt < 1;
            $wantedBcnt = 9 if $wantedBcnt > 9;
            my $wantedBstr = sprintf("aaa%s", "B" x $wantedBcnt);

            $line =~ s/^aaaB+/$wantedBstr/;
        }
        $out .= $line . "\n";
    }
    return($out);
}
```

the new version based on Zaid's answer:

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;

my $mytext = "some text
aaaB some another text
text3 here
aaaBB some text4
another textxxx
aaaBBBBXX some text4
another textzzzz
";

say change_ab(8, $mytext);

sub change_ab {
    $_[1] =~ s{(?<=^aaa)(B+)}{ 'B' x fixshift(length($1)+$_[0]) }gem;
    return $_[1];
}

sub fixshift {
    return 9 if $_[0] > 9;
    return 1 if $_[0] < 1;
    return $_[0];
}
```

Ps: if someone can give a better question title - pls. change it.

Comment: OMG - my bad - I forgot write down than in the result i need at least 1B or max 9Bs. I has these checks in my source - but unfortunately i forgot write this into the text... all solutions what i got, make from "aaaB" only "aaa". my bad. ;(

Comment: Instead of `fixshift`, I'd say there's enough tweaking going on to justify the use of a helper variable: `s{...}{ my $reps = length($1) + $_[0]; 'B' x $reps < 1 ? 1 : $reps > 9 ? 9 : $reps }`. Now that I look at it, it seems that you need to revisit the bigger picture to understand why you need to do such a complicated operation in the first place.

Comment: Simply, the input has defined format - coming from an bigger system, so can't change it. Output format must be the same as input (will replace it). And i need change the number of 'B's. Thats all. Your solution is brilliant. Thanx. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let the `/e` modifier do the heavy-lifting for you:

```
$mytext =~ s{(?<=^aaa)([bB]+)}{ 'B' x (length($1) + $b_shift) }gem;
```

---

If `$b_shift` is expected to vary, wrap the operation in a single sub:

```
sub change_ab {

    my $b_shift = +shift ;   # $_[0] = b_shift,  $_[1] = text

                             # After shift, $_[0] is text

    $_[0] =~ s{(?<=^aaa)([bB]+)}{ 'B' x (length($1) + $b_shift) }gem;

    return $_[0];  # Explicit return avoids scalar context interpolation
}
```

#### Usage

```
my $mytext = 
"some text
aaaB some another text
text3 here
aaaBB some text4
another textxxx
aaaBBBBXX some text4
another textzzzz
";

change_ab ( -1, $mytext );  

print $mytext;
```

#### Output

```
some text
aaa some another text
text3 here
aaaB some text4
another textxxx
aaaBBBXX some text4
another textzzzz
```

Comment: tested this first, because it is really nice and short!  but in the result i must get at least one B, so when shifting negative, so from aaaB I should get "aaaB" and not only "aaa". And at the other side, when shifting +7 from "aaaBBBB" I should get max 9 Bs and not 11 (aaaBBBBBBBBB)

Comment: accepted this - because gave me a new idea how to redone my script... ;) thanx.

Comment: @jm666 : I'm sure you can adapt this idea to put limits on your 'B' repetitions, although let this be a lesson; the answers you get will be only as good as the question you ask.

Answer (score 1):

This should also do the job:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.10.1;

sub change_ab {
   my ($shift, $string) = @_;

   while ($string =~ m/[^#](aaaB+)/m) {
      my $numB = length($1)-3; # account for 'aaa' by '-3'

      # if the new number of 'B's would be negative, just keep
      # the old number; 0 'B's is allowed though (otherwise change
      # '>= 0' to '> 0')
      my $new_numB = ($numB + $shift >= 0) ? $numB + $shift : $numB;

      # add '#' to mark this instance of aaaB+ as modified already
      my $replacement = sprintf "#aaa%s", 'B' x $new_numB;

      # replace the FIRST non-modified instance of aaaB+, i.e. the
      # one we've just been working on
      $string =~ s/(?<=[^#])aaaB+/$replacement/;
   }

   $string =~ s/#(aaaB*)/$1/g; # remove the '#' markers
   return $string;
}

my $mytext = "some text
aaaB some another text
text3 here
aaaBB some text4
another textxxx
aaaBBBBXX some text4
another textzzzz
";

say change_ab(-1, $mytext);
```

The output when you remove one 'B', as in the code above, is as follows:

```
some text
aaa some another text
text3 here
aaaB some text4
another textxxx
aaaBBBXX some text4
another textzzzz
```